# Polymer with PHP and seperate server

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, npm, polymer

I've managed to get Polymer setup with an application and can test it using "polymer serve". However I would also like to use it with PHP. I have an Apache PHP server setup in OSX but when I view my project I get the following message:

```
"@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

I have tried using the "polymer build" command and running from that folder but no success. Anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'd write an API with PHP and make AJAX calls to it from your node app.

Comment: Keep them separate? That's actually a good shout - would that hamper load times as oppose to pure PHP?

Comment: I don't think it will, but you don't have any other option anyway as far as I can see, since polymer relies on the node server.